# Problems with BindlingList<T> and combo box

Tags: c#, binding, combobox

I have got the following code:

```
private BindingList<INoun> _nouns;

private BindingList<INoun> Nouns
{
    get
    {
        if ( _nouns == null )
        {
            _nouns = new BindingList<INoun>( _model.Feature.Nouns );
            _nouns.Insert( 0, new Noun( -1, "Please select..." ) );
        }
        return _nouns;
    }
}


public interface INoun
{
    int Id;
    string Text;
}
```

The `Nouns` property is bound to a `ComboBox` that adds a default entry `Please select...` to the `BindingList`.

The issue I am having here is that the `Please select...` entry is unexpectedly being added to the underlying`_model.Feature.Nouns` collection and I do not want this to happen.

Is there anyway I can add a `Please select...` default item to a ComboBox without it being added to the underlying collection?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BindingList` is just a wrapper, mainly to get notifications, around your `_model.Feature.Nouns` which remains as the underlying List of items (that's why you have `AllowEdit, AllowNew, AllowRemove` on `BindingList`) :

If you want to work on a brand new list (though I'm not sure it's the purpose of the BindingList), try :

```
_nouns = new BindingList<INoun>( _model.Feature.Nouns.Select(x=>x).ToList());
```

Comment: I have been using the BindingList as a data source for the combo box rather than doing a `foreach` loop, manually adding the nouns to the combobox.  Your suggestion works perfectly so I will accept that as your answer.